# how to load deparment wise record for each run in informatica?

Tags: informatica

For example,i have 10,20,30,40..... deparment no, for first run need to load only 10 deparment no records, for second run need to load 20 deparment no records only soon for each each run each deparment no record

Please help,Thanks

Comment: Use a mapping parameter to pass the department no. Change it for each run through script.

Comment: What is a "department no" ?

Comment: Provide your complete structure of data. Whether its a flat file or database?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ROUTER transformation for loading department wise then add one more condition like

```
for dept no=10  ==> Dept no=10 and COUNT(LKP(in target table having dept no=10))=0
```

likewise u can use in the remaining dept nos....